# NSURLConnection Delegate methods are not getting called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macos, asynchronous

I have had this problem and i went through so many posts here on stack overflow and everywhere else and couldnt find a solution. Im running it on the main thread as well. Code as follows.

```
@interface JsonViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate,UIWebViewDelegate,NSURLConnectionDelegate>
{
  ....
}
@implementation JsonViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
    rssFeedDetailViewConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"PRINTING RSS FEED %@", rssFeedDetailViewConnection);
[rssFeedDetailViewConnection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] 
                                       forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [rssFeedDetailViewConnection start];
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
NSLog(@"Hello");
responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
     NSLog(@"Hello");
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
     NSLog(@"Hello");
    [responseData release];
    [connection release];
// Show error message
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
 NSLog(@"Hello");
    // Use responseData
    [responseData release];
    [connection release];
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Ive been stuck with this for two days now..

Comment: Try sending a synchronous request then you would not need to call delegates.

Comment: Yes it works with synchronous requests but the problem is its taking too long unless i use threading to put it on another thread that solution is not idea. - thanks

Comment: I tried your code.It is getting called.Try cleaning your project and run again.

Comment: Yes,your code works fine,try to get the output string in method :
`- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [connection release];
 
    responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Resp String : %@",responseString);
 self.responseData = nil;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need these statements:

```
[rssFeedDetailViewConnection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]  forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[rssFeedDetailViewConnection start];
```

since you're using `initWithRequest:delegate:`. This call already starts loading the data.

What happens if you remove these particular statements?

More info on the [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Did take that off and didnt work as well.. But i have found the solution which i will post below.

Answer (score 0):

Have a boolean called finished and add this code where ever you have written your NSURLConnection Code.

```
 while(!finished) {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}
```

and in your connectionDidFinishLoading just add this

```
 finished = TRUE;
```

and that works. Its not the best solution i understand but it works.